# MongoDB understanding MMS charts

Tags: mongodb, charts, monitoring

I'm really new to mongo,

I have to monitor a mongodb instance during tests of a system using it. I have trouble understanding charts provided by the MMS agent. Here are my questions:

1 - I bother about performances and availability, which charts should I focus on ?

2 - In the opcounters chart, they say: "The number of commands performed per unit time" What is the unit of time ? Also in this same chart what is the difference between "command" and "queries" ? What is "getmore" ?

I think that's enough questions for a start, might be more coming up following answers :)

Regards,
Robin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For performance I suggest looking at opcounters, lock%, page faults, btree and queues. For availability (I am assuming you have a replica set since you mention availability) watch out for replica and repl lag graphs. By no means is the above list supposed to be exhaustive but merely as a starting reference when you are diagnosing performance issues.
2. Per unit of time : It is the time per second if that is what is highlighted on the top of the page. Commands are different from queries (Fetching server stats, initializing a replica set, and running a map-reduce job are all accomplished by running a command).
   As you iterate through the cursor and reach the end of the returned batch, if there are more results, cursor.next() will perform a "getmore" operation to retrieve the next batch.

Comment: great thx for your answer, I will dig on my own for now, you put me on the right tracks cheers. PS: how do I know my instance reaches its limit, for example in the opcounters, how do I know it can't go faster ?

Comment: High lock percent (it means heavy write lock contention) and page faults (working set bigger than available memory) would be a couple of things where I would begin with. Measuring Network and disk saturation will also be helpful.

Comment: Ok my last question will concern the btree. How is it used by mongo and how do I should interpet the results ?

Comment: MongoDB uses Btree based indexes. The btree MMS graph shows misses (the number of times a btree page was not in memory) and hits (when the page was in memory). You want to make sure that most of the btree accesses are hits. A large number of misses means that you are indexes are too big to fit in RAM, which can cause a significant performance penalty. You can read more here : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/

Comment: It seems the Lock% graph is gone in 3.0.5. Wonder whether that was a marketing decision...